# WSO2 IOT : is Apple VPP or DEP available now in wso2?

Tags: wso2, mdm, apple-vpp, wso2-iot

As the question suggests, anyone know if the WSO2 IOT Server supports apple DEP or VPP for MDM management?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 IoT Server does support DEP. However, the implementation is still in experimental form and we have not merged the features to the main product as yet. You can expect DEP support to be available in future releases.

Comment: so technically i cant use it today? and can i use VPP out of the box or no? thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Not at the moment.